# Codeceptjs returns NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when running tests via Github actions

Tags: github-actions, playwright, codeceptjs

I'm making e2e tests with Codeceptjs (Playwright) and tests work as intended locally. But as soon as I move tests to Github actions runner, they fail completely (the first one dies, and then the job stops completely).

***codecept.confg.ts***

```
helpers: {
        Playwright: {
            url: process.env.SL_URL,
            show: false,
            browser: 'firefox',
            keepCookies: true,
            restart: 'session',
            firefox: {
                args: [
                    "--disable-web-security",
                    "--allow-insecure-localhost",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                    "--ignore-ssl-errors",
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "-–allow-file-access-from-files",
                ],
            },
        }
    },
```

I tried everything from allowing ports to changing the runner to a different version (Ubuntu latest to Ubuntu 20) to switching to Chromium and removing Firefox config args (above)

***GitHub actions runner output***
[image]